Radon-Nikodym and Lebesgue Decomposition
The Lebesgue decomposition theorem asserts that for if $\lambda$ is a $\sigma$ finite measure and $\mu$ a $\sigma$ finite signed measure, then we can decompose $\mu$ into $\mu_a$ and $\mu_s$ such that
$\mu_a<< \lambda$ and $\mu_s \perp \lambda$.
Now the Radon-Nikodym Theorem states that if $\lambda$ is $\sigma$ finite measure and $\mu$ is a measure such that $\mu << \lambda$, then $\mu$ can be "representated" by $\mu(A):=\int_A f d \lambda$for $f \in L^1$.
I am trying to understand the usefulness of the Radon Nikodym Theorem.
It states that a measure, under the right conditions, can be represented by integrals.
And the Lebesgue decomposition Theorem asserts that one can decompose a measure to get the "absolutely continuous" part.
Thinking about those, the following question arose:
What is the use of being able to represent a measure by integral?
The second question is regarding the application:
Given a $\sigma$ finite measure $\mu$. How can one find a measure $\lambda$ to apply the Lebesgue decomposition? (I have been thinking about just using the Lebesgue measure as $\lambda$ and decompose $\mu$ into $\mu_a$ and $\mu_s$.)

You can use Radon Nikodym to prove existence of conditional expectations or find the dual space of $L^p$ (just two examples, there are many many more)

What is the use of being able to represent a measure by integral?
We can calculate integrals! The Radon-Nikodym theorem tells you precisely what are the measures that are basically just Lebesgue measure, weighted against some $L^1$ function. This is super important in probability: it lets you show that the probability that an event $E$ occurs is the integral of some density function over $E$. The probability density is the function $f$ that you wrote down.

But isn't it a problem that for any given measure $\mu$ I need to decompose it into an absolutely continuous $\mu_a$ and singular measure $mu_s$. Although I can then represent $\mu_a$ by integration, I still can't say alot about $\mu$.
